# failing using call by reference to take the function return object value

Tags: javascript, redux, pass-by-reference

Now I implement a function of finding users in user groups. These are nested groups, so the search is realized by recursive calls. My codes are listed bellow; I also use redux.

I use searchGroupUserAcc to call search to get the target group that contains the specified user. I've confirmed that the parameter targetGroup is assigned correctly, but I don't know why its value is still {} after the search is done.

I am very confused; all ideas are welcome. Thanks.

```
function search(groups)(groups, tokenAcc, targetGroup){
    ...
    //search in a group; g is one group is groups
    for(let i=0;i<g.userList.length;++i) {
        if(g.userList[i]===tokenAcc) {
            //confirmed that targetGroup's value is not{}
            targetGroup=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(g));
            return;
        }
    }
    //for searching subGroups 
    search(...);

}

//tokenAcc is the user account key used to search in the group array.
export function searchGroupUserAcc(tokenAcc){
     return (dispatch)=>{
         ...
         let targetG={};
         //use tokenAcc to search in groups. every group in groups contains the useraccount info
         //expect targetG to hold the return value.
         search(tokenAcc, groups,targetG);
         console.log(targetG);//still prints{}, but why
     };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you return the value from your `search` function directly?

```
if(g.userList[i]===tokenAcc) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(g));
}
```

and then in your second function: `targetG = search(tokenAcc, groups,targetG);`

**EDIT**

Given that you are using redux, I would highly suggest you move to a more *functional* and *pure* approach, which, among other things, implies that you avoid side effects (i.e. what you are doing right now) and always use the return value of a function. Have a look at the official redux [documentation](https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles) for more information about it

Comment: Surely I could do that. It's just that in that way I also need to return proper values when handling leaf (in my group tree) cases, being some extra work. It is my last resort

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Hy Buddy.

Javascript is always pass by value, but when a variable refers to an object, the "value" is a reference to the object.

So if you changing the value of a variable never changes the underlying primitive or object, it just points the variable to a new primitive or object.